# Query Mongoose aggregate

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I canned resolve this thanks to @chridam but... exists other form to resolve this without the mongoose object?

the code:

```
Cliente.aggregate([
        { $match: {
            _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.cliente_id)
        }},
        { $unwind: "$vsat" },
        { $match: { 
            "vsat._id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.vsat_id)
        }},
        { $project: { 
            vsat: 1,
            _id: 0 
        }}
    ], function(err, data) {
        if (err) throw (err);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        res.json(data);
    });
```

This is my schema:

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    razonSocial: String,
    cuit: String,
    vsat: [{
        CPA: Number,
        IP: String,
    }]
});
```

Comment: Your req.params.vsat_id is string not object

Comment: @Sumeet  Please can you give me more details??

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show the schema definition for `Cliente` model?

Comment: I add the Schema now :D @chridam

Comment: Awesome. To help you with the debugging, what is the result you get when you run a pipeline with just the first stage `Cliente.aggregate([
        { $match: {
            _id: req.params.cliente_id 
        }}
    ], function(err, data) {
        if (err) throw (err);
        res.json('DATA:'+data);
    });` ?

Comment: Your second `$match` is a different query. You need to use dot notation in the Mongoose query there, just like in the console.

Comment: @chridam `Cliente.aggregate([
        { $match: {
            _id: req.params.cliente_id 
        }}
    ], function(err, data) {
        if (err) throw (err);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        res.json(data);
    });`
This returns : [] empy

Comment: @chridam with the dot notation i have the same problem 'vsat._id' . This returns empty too

Comment: @chridam this query is work

`Cliente.aggregate([ { $match: { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId('587cc2d8704ae610d3741e6b') }} ], function(err, data) { if (err) throw (err); console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); res.json(data); });`

Comment: @chridam and this too 

`Cliente.aggregate([ { $match: { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.cliente_id) }} ], function(err, data) { if (err) throw (err); console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); res.json(data); });`

Comment: @MatiasCeliz It's better if you can [edit] your question to show the code that you're trying now instead of doing it in the comments where there isn't any formatting.

Comment: @JohnnyHK when the code are more aceptable i will modify. This are just a test